# Google Apps Script: Why are equal strings/values coming up as not equal

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have equal strings coming up as not equal in a google apps script function and can't figure out why. Other answers to this question on the forum are in other languages I don't understand yet. Here's the code:

```
function testForMatch() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Leaderboard');
  var masterLength = masterSheet.getMaxRows() - 3;
  var masterData = masterSheet.getRange(4, 2, masterLength).getValues();      //gets all the student names from the leaderboard

  var titleSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Title - Standard scores');
  var titleLength = titleSheet.getMaxRows() -3;
  var titleData = titleSheet.getRange(4, 2, titleLength).getValues();    //gets all the student names from the standard score sheet

  for ( i = 0; i < masterLength; i ++) {
    if(masterData[i] != titleData[i]) {
      var row = i + 1;
      var error = "Uh oh! It looks like " + masterData[i] + " and " + titleData[i] + " do not match in row " + row;
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert(error);
    }
  }
}
```

even if I just type simple strings into the matching cells it tells me they don't match. Likewise for numbers.

Only thing I can think is that my script isn't actually comparing the values. If that's true, how do I get it to do that?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(masterData[i][0] != titleData[i][0]) {`

...would compare the cell values